# PeopleEditor auto complete 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise

I am working on a custom solution for SP2010 and the customer ask me to make PeopleEditor auto complete like OOB PeopleEditor on SP2013

Can any one help me accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

This is very good article which helps to make custom people picker control.
http://karinebosch.wordpress.com/sharepoint-controls/peopleeditor-control/

Article is for MOSS 2007 But I am sure you can use it for SP 2010